# VueJS 2.x Child-Component doesn't react to changed parent-property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have the problem, that a component doesn't recognize the change of a property.
The component is nested about 5 levels deep. Every component above the faulty one does update with the same mechanics and flawlessly.
I invested some time to get to the problem, but I can't find it.

The flow is:

- Dashboard (change value and pass as prop)
- TicketPreview (Usage and
  pass prop)
- CommentSection (Pass prop)
- CommentList (FAULTY / Usage of prop)

Everything down to the commentSection is being updated as expected, but the commentList doesn't get the update notification (beforeUpdate doesn't get triggered).

Since I tested quite a few things I will only post the essential code from commentSection (parent) and commenList (child)

> DISCLAIMER: This is a prototype code without backend, therefore typical API-Requests are solved with the localStorage of the users browser.

**commentSection**

```
<template>
  <div id="comment-section">
    <p>{{selectedTicket.title}}</p>
    <comment-form :selectedTicket="selectedTicket" />
    <comment-list :selectedTicket="selectedTicket" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import CommentForm from "@/components/comment-section/CommentForm";
  import CommentList from "@/components/comment-section/CommentList";

  export default {
    name: "CommentSection",
    components: {
      CommentForm,
      CommentList,
    },
    props: {
      selectedTicket: Object,
    },
    beforeUpdate() {
      console.log("Comment Section");
      console.log(this.selectedTicket);
    },
    updated() {
      console.log("Comment Section is updated");
    }
  }
</script>
```

**CommentList**

```
<template>
  <div id="comment-list">
    <comment-item
         v-for="comment in comments"
         :key="comment.id"
         :comment="comment"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import CommentItem from "@/components/comment-section/CommentItem";

  export default {
    name: "CommentList",
    components: {
      CommentItem,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        comments: Array,
      }
    },
    props: {
      selectedTicket: Object,
    },
    methods: {
      getComments() {
        let comments = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("comments"));
        let filteredComments = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < comments.length; i++){
          if (comments[i].ticketId === this.selectedTicket.id){
            filteredComments.push(comments[i]);
          }
        }
        this.comments = filteredComments;
      }
    },
    beforeUpdate() {
      console.log("CommentList");
      console.log(this.selectedTicket);
      this.getComments();
    },
    mounted() {
      this.$root.$on("updateComments", () => {
        this.getComments();
      });
      console.log("CL Mounted");
    },
  }
</script>
```

The `beforeUpdate()` and `updated()` hooks from the **commentList component** are not being fired.
I guess I could work around it with an event passing the data, but for the sake of understanding, let's pretend it's not a viable option right now.

Comment: from my understanding of the question, are you saying that the rendering doesn't work even though the comments array in the CommentList has changed?

Comment: @Taylous the commentList doesn't even bother to update, even though commenSection and it's property "selectedTicket" has been updated. commentSection fires the console.logs but commentList never even reaches the beforeUpdate() hook.

Comment: my guess is that in the getComments() method, Vue doesn't detect changes to the object. So, delete the "this.comment = filteredComments" syntax and put the object directly into "this.comment" (like "this.comment.push(comments[i]))

Comment: @Taylous I'll try it, but even without calling the method getComments() the component commentList doesn't even update(or get triggered in any way) when the prop on it's parent changes (which it should by definition). [VueJS Prop One Way Data Flow](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow)

Comment: @Taylous ` So, delete the "this.comment = filteredComments" syntax and put the object directly into "this.comment"` -> doesn't work (sadly)

Comment: Okay... "this.$root.$on("updateComments",..." Have you checked whether the event works?

Comment: @Taylous As mentioned in the post: The eventListeners are not the problem. The problem is, that the (Vue)native Hooks for updated() and beforeUpdate() are not triggered, even though the parent has a changed value on the watched prop. I COULD use Events for this, but I can't in this situation. I just need to know why the beforeUpdate and updated events are not called, even though the parents watched property changed.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use a watcher, this will be more simple.

Instead of method to set comments by filtering you can use computed property which is reactive and no need to watch for props updates.

**CommentSection**

```
<template>
    <div id="comment-section">
        <p>{{ selectedTicket.title }}</p>
        <comment-form :selectedTicket="selectedTicket" />
        <comment-list :selectedTicket="selectedTicket" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import CommentForm from "@/components/comment-section/CommentForm";
import CommentList from "@/components/comment-section/CommentList";

export default {
    name: "CommentSection",
    components: {
        CommentForm,
        CommentList
    },
    props: {
        selectedTicket: Object
    },
    methods: {
        updateTicket() {
            console.log("Comment section is updated");
            console.log(this.selectedTicket);
        }
    },
    watch: {
        selectedTicket: {
            immediate: true,
            handler: "updateTicket"
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

**CommentList**

```
<template>
    <div id="comment-list">
        <comment-item
            v-for="comment in comments"
            :key="comment.id"
            :comment="comment"
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import CommentItem from "@/components/comment-section/CommentItem";

export default {
    name: "CommentList",
    components: {
        CommentItem
    },
    props: {
        selectedTicket: Object
    },
    computed: {
        comments() {
            let comments = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("comments"));

            let filteredComments = [];
            for (let comment of comments) {
                if (comment.ticketId == this.selectedTicket.id) {
                    filteredComments.push(comment);
                }
            }

            // // using es6 Array.filter()
            // let filteredComments = comments.filter(
            //   (comment) => comment.ticketId == this.selectedTicket.id
            // );
            return filteredComments;
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I found the problem in my solution, the info from the wiki was faulty (or otherwise simply badly written). nonetheless: I adapted parts of your solution to make the code cleaner, thank you very much for your effort and answer, even if it didn't target my problem, you still improved my workflow and code.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: Since commentList is only a wrapper that doesn't use any of the values from the prop, the hooks for beforeUpdate and updated are never triggered. The [Vue Instance Chart](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) is misleading in that regard. The diagram shows it like beforeUpdate would ALWAYS fire, when the data changed (then re-render, then updated), but beforeUpdate only fires if the Component and Parent has to be re-rendered.
The Object updates as expected, it just never triggered a re-render on the child component because the wrapper has not been re-rendered.